# Make F1 short cut key in Swing

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Java Swing app in Which I have been able to set shortcut keys using the following piece of code. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

```
keyHelp.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_K, Event.CTRL_MASK));
keyHelp.setMnemonic((int) 'K');//This is the Line I need Help in
```

I just can't figure out how to add the same using <kbd>F1</kbd> key as the shortcut... Could anyone please help?

Comment: There is `KeyEvent.VK_F1` Does it not work using it ?

Comment: Perhaps this could be of any help to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019371/swing-setting-a-function-key-f2-as-an-accelerator

Comment: `KeyEvent.VK_F1` is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html#eg), can make these settings easier to manage. Also consider `getMenuShortcutKeyMask()` instead of assuming `Event.CTRL_MASK`.

Answer (score 4):

use,

**KeyEvent.VK_F1**

I think it will help you.

Comment: This `keyHelp.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, '0'));` is Nnot working

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make your shortcut key just "F1" without CTRL, It should be like this,

```
keyHelp.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0));
```