# Create java swing application to display GUI only when ctrl+c is pressed

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, jframe, copy-paste

I want to create a Java swing application which **loads GUI only when Ctrl+C is pressed**.

When I start the application, it should monitor keyboard events such that when `Ctrl+C` is pressed, GUI (`JFrame`) is displayed. I don't want to display any part of GUI till `Ctrl+C` is pressed.

I am unable to find **how to associate keyboard event before any GUI component is realized.** Is it possible to show `JFrame` i.e. `frame.setVisible(true)` conditionally on keyboard capture ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: @TNT You need a JComponent for that, which isn't available (yet).

Comment: @Charlie Right... forgot that JFrame doesn't extend JComponent.

Comment: @TNT Even if it would, it wouldn't have any focus (As it is not visible), so it wouldn't register any keys. At sks, I think you would need [raw input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it) in a while loop to check for CTRL+C.

Comment: Intent of my application is to run it as windows desktop application which will keep running as any other windows application and whenever user tries to copy  any content using ctrl+c from other windows, my application should capture the event and display copied content in my application's GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## On Linux/Unix

With a bit of help from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it):

```
// Setting console to raw mode
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "stty raw </dev/tty"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).waitFor();

// Getting input stream
Console console = System.console();
Reader reader = console.reader();

// Checking if input is ^C
char c=0;
while(c!=3) { // 3 = ^C
    c=(char)reader.read();
}
// ^C is entered

// Reset console to normal mode
cmd = new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c", "stty sane </dev/tty"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).waitFor();   

// Initialize frame
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
frame.setSize(400,200);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setTitle("Why are you leaving me ?");
frame.setVisible(true);
```

## On Windows/Macintosh

It doesn't seem to be possible with Java's own libraries. [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) could work [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23179249/4141219) with this code:

```
ConsoleReader reader = new ConsoleReader();
char c=0;
while(c!=3) {
    c=(char)reader.readVirtualKey();
}
// Frame stuff here
```

I think the comments explain everything you need. If not, let me know!

*Sidenote*: If you run this in Eclipse you'll get an NPE at `Reader reader=console.reader()`, because that's the way Eclipse runs its programs; without a console.

Comment: What if it's Windows?:)

Comment: Its intended to be a windows application :) By the way, how do other windows application which are built in Swing capture keyboard events ? Is it possible if I associate Function key like F12 instead of ctrl-c ?

Comment: @sks You could've followed the link, but I added the code in my own post.

Comment: Yes, saw the latest code. Thanks !! I will try to run it and get back. Great help !

Comment: @sks In the meantime, please accept my answer :) About the F-keys: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8903396/4141219)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread hook)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).

`Ctrl + C` initiates `SIGINT`, this will cause JVM to shutdown, and then your hook will be invoked. Then you can add some loop with condition (to finalize JVM shutdown when it's needed) and `Thread.sleep()`.

As another option, you can use Sun's `Signal` class from `sun.misc` package.

```
SignalHandler handler = (_) -> {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Title");
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
};

Signal.handle(new Signal("INT"), handler);
```

**EDIT**
To catch key combinations across the system, you can use [jkeymaster](https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster) lib.

Comment: Ehm, the frame will then flash and the program will close?

Comment: @Charlie, no, if you use for example `Thread.sleep`, I've updated my answer. Thanks.